# Embed text inside image

Tags: android

I want to display a custom text (mainly person info) inside image

[image]

How can I do it in android? For example I have a known size of this image (it differs from device to device) and want to display it with the different text size inside it in the special place (example is above in link).

Comment: I am guessing you want to display text over the image ?

Comment: I want to make this part transparent before and then yes, try to fit the text into this transparent part. As for my knowledge from .net, the only possible way is a drawing over the image.

Comment: Look up how to work your XML layouts.  Overlapping is easy.  And setting dependencies as per device is also easy.

Comment: why dont use simple textview over image, both in relativelayout and then position them as you like?

Comment: thanks, i did not know overlapping is so easy. I should google first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

The way I would do it is to make the image into a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). Either don't allow it to stretch, or mark areas outside of the character to stretch. In either case, use the right and bottom regions to mark where in the image you want the text to go.

Then you simply set the 9-patch as the background for a `TextView`, and your text will be placed in the region you marked in the 9-patch.

An alternative method would be to use a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, then just position the TextView where you need it. However, I find dealing with trying to position views perfectly using this method to be tedious and error-prone. A 9-patch would also allow you to use this image with nearly any length of text without worrying about the text running outside the content region.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image as the background of a layout, then add one or multiple textview(s) inside that layout and play around with the margins a bit until it fits

For example something looking like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/firstLine"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/secondLine"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="2"
     android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I suggested in comment earlier, put `ImageView` and `TextView` in `RelativeLayout`, something like this (properties are random):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#ff1234"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Image"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6363"
        android:background="#ff0034" />
</RelativeLayout>
```