# Why nine-patch is scaled horizontally

Tags: android, nine-patch

As an addition to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474467/embed-text-inside-image), I have a image and want to place text inside the image. I've created a `nine-patch` image but it scaled incorrectly - I want to leave part of the image unchanged.

**original file**

[image]

It's how it looks in editor

[image]

this how it looks in preview (and in my sample app with width more than image width

[image]

So I want to scale only text part and leave the 'head' and 'fingers' unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper part (black border) tells the 9 patch to stretch the "head part" too.

Please consider using two pixels at the sides of the "no stretch zone".
Something like: `.                   .`
This way you'd have 2 horizontally stretched areas, leaving the head unstretched.

**[EDIT]**

At last, I saw you put the image, so here's my patched version, just in case.

[image]

Comment: you were enough clear so i've edit my file myself before your edit, thx!

Comment: OK, just as an exercise for me, then... ;)